# Keeping multiple area chart width's fixed

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence

Is there a way to fix an area graph's width? So when I have multiple columns, they don't shrink. How can I have a normal scroller, similar to a text tables.

Just 5 Columns:[image: 5 Dimensions/columns]

Multiple Columns in same panel width: [image: Multiple dims/cols]

Scroller: [image: Scroller]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your dashboard, from the sheet dropdown menu:

Fit > Standard

[image]

Here is an article from Tableau that references the issue:

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/view-on-dashboard-is-scrunched-and-has-no-scrollbar